# ImageObserver not working

Tags: java, image

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get ImageObserver to work. I thought this would work. I'd like it to print a message when the image loads but it doesn't... What am I doing wrong? This can probably be answered easily.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class ImageTest extends JPanel implements ImageObserver {

    @Override
    public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y,
            int width, int height) {
        if((infoflags & ALLBITS) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Processing still");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Done processing");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    BufferedImage img;

    public ImageTest (){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("res/soccer-ball.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(new ImageTest());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1000, 1000);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: ImageIO guarantees  that the image will be fully loaded when it returns (it throws an exception if the image can not be loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting it in the drawImage simply use the ToolKit to process your image where you will use the instance of your `ImageObserver` to prepare the image

**change this:**

```
try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("res/soccer-ball.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**to:**

```
public class ImageTest extends JPanel implements ImageObserver {

@Override
public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y,
        int width, int height) {
    if((infoflags & ALLBITS) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Processing still");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Done processing");
        repaint();
        return false;
    }
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}

Image img;

public ImageTest (){
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    img =  toolkit.getImage("res/soccer-ball.jpg");
    toolkit.prepareImage(img, -1, -1, this);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setContentPane(new ImageTest());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(1000, 1000);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Where you need to `repaint` the `JPanel` when the image is finished processing or else the image wont show.

Comment: `ImageIO` guarantees that the image is loaded when `read` returns (or throws an exception if the image can not be loaded), also, it supports a wider range of image formats and provides a extendible library. IMHO, falling backwards to API that doesn't guarantee the state of the image (ever) seems, well, backwards

Comment: Or not. Anyways I replaced it with ImageIO and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, `JPanel` already implements `ImageObserver`, so overriding `imageUpdate` in this way likely breaks the panel's normal functionality.

Also, you implement `ImageObserver` but never subscribe/register to observe anything.

Try this:

```
...

@Override
public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
  if ((infoflags & ALLBITS) == 0) {
    System.out.println("Processing still");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Done processing");
  }
  return super.imageUpdate(img, infoflags, x, y, w, h);
}

...

public ImageTest() {
  try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("res/soccer-ball.jpg"));
    prepareImage(img, this);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

...
```